# Getting values from two types of sensors in android

Tags: android, android-sensors

Good day all, I'm trying to make an app with two types of sensors(ACCELEROMETER & LIGHT) and I need their values to change profile or whatever I want. The problem is I can't figure it out how to get values from different sensors. Here are my codes,

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor mySensor = event.sensor;
    Sensor LightSense = event.sensor;
    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER && LightSense.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        float light = event.values[0];

        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            if (light<=100) {
                myAudManHolder.silent();
            }else if (x<=0 && y<=0 && z<=+9){
                myAudManHolder.ring();
            }else if (x<=2 && y<=-7 && z<=-1){
                myAudManHolder.vibrate();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

How can I get the values from ACCELEROMETER & LIGHT sensors both? Your help would be really appreciable. Tnx.

Comment: `mySensor.getType()` cannot equal 2 different sensors, it either one or the other

Comment: @tyczj, But I used two different variables for two sensors, `mySensor` and `LightSense`.

Comment: what...no its the same sensor event twice

Comment: Ok event is same. So how can I take two separate events for two sensors? Should I add another parameter for another event?

Comment: How about using timestamps to ensure that two sensor values are at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this

```
if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
    //use acc data and light sensor data together
}else if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT){
    //save light sensor data for later use
}
```

there is no way to get multiple sensors data at the same time